# SharePoint 2013 - Export site error

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, export, sub-site

I have a problem by exporting a SharePoint Site by using `Export-SPWeb` on my SharePoint 2013 server.

The error code is:

> Export-SPWeb: These columns don't currently have unique values.

Is it possible to export a site by ignoring this message or is there another solution for this error?

Comment: Is the site that you are trying to export a evaluation site? https://blog.areflyen.no/2014/01/13/export-spweb-fails-with-these-columns-dont-currently-have-unique-values/

Answer (score 0):

> You may try to export via `stsadm.exe` command as written here:
>
> [Move SharePoint Site Collection as a Subsite](http://sharepointserved.blogspot.com/2011/03/move-site-collection-as-subsite.html)
>
> [Moving SharePoint sites using stsadm.exe](http://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2012/07/moving-sharepoint-sites-using-stsadm-exe/)
>
> This command has different behavior then sharepoint powershell
> Export-SPWeb command.

Comment: is my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Start "Run site collection health checks" under Site Settings : Site Collection Health Checks and fix those problems before exporting the site/web.
I had to reset some pages to site definition, for example.